# What is a formula for the number of strings with no repeats?

Tags: formal-languages, combinatorics, strings, word-combinatorics

I want to count the number of strings $s$ over a finite alphabet $A$, that contain no repeats, and by that I mean for any substring $t$ of $s$, $1< |t| < |s|$, there is no disjoint copy of $t$ in $s$.  For exapmle, let $A=\{a,b\}$.  Then $aaa$ *is* one of the strings I want to count, since for the substring $aa$, there are no disjoint copies.  However, $abab$ contains such a repeat.

If someone's already figured out a useful formula, please link.  Otherwise, I will refer back to this post in any article I write, if I use someone's answer.

Here is another example.  Let's try to construct a long string over $\{a,b\}$, that contains no repeats:

aaa (can't be a)  
   aaab (a or b)  
     aaabbb (can't be b) 
       aaabbba (can't be b or a) 
   aaaba (can't be a or b)

If we built a tree, we could count the number of nodes, but I want a formula.

**Edit:**
Well, it's not as daunting as I first thought if we convert this to a bin-choosing problem.  A set of strings of length k with at least one repeat is equal to the set that is the union of all permutations of the cartesian product:
$A \times A \times \cdots\times A \text{(k-4 times)} \times R \times R$ where $R$ is the required repeat.  I don't know if that's helpful, but it sounded pro :)  Anyway, let their be |A| bins, choose any two (even if the same one) to be the repeat, then choose $k-4$ more and multiply (the first 4 are already chosen, see?).  Now I just need to find that formula from discrete math.

Comment: why there is no disjoint copy in $aaa$? isn't $t=a$ a valid substring of $s=aa$, that is, $s=tt$? Can you give couple more examples to clarify what should and shouldn't be count?

Comment: Notice $1 <|t|$ requirement.  Let me know if / how I can write my post clearer.

Comment: yea, I missed this requirement. It makes more sense now.

Comment: I guess it should be $n^k - {n^2}{n^{k-4}} = n^k - n^{k-2} $, right?  Lol

Comment: You should be more specific, i.e. you should state in the question that you want to count the number of string of length $n$, otherwise if you just want the number of all of them the answer is infinite.

Comment: What I want to count I think is finite.  Take ${a,b}$.  The number of strings of length $4 $ that have repeats:
aaaa, abab, baba, bbbb.  So there are $2^4 - 4$ with no repeats.  As $k$ goes up, it becomes impossible to construct a string of length $k$ containing no repeats.  For $|A| = 2$, this $k$ is around 7 or 8, just by writing down possible strings.

Comment: I'm not seeing how (with a 2 letter alphabet for example) you can construct a string of length (say) 10 with no repeats. i.e the desired number must be upper bounded by some function of k independent of n

Comment: @Suresh, yes that is correct.  So I want to write the size of the set of strings with no repeats $|S|$ as a function of $|A|$, the alphabet size.  And if a formula for $k$ in terms of $|A|$ is also easily expressed, that would also be useful to me.  IOW, I think |S| will depend on |A|, involve a sum over $k$, the terms of which eventually vanish, then there is a formula involving $k$ and $|A|$.

Comment: Revised formula for number of k-strings with no repeats:
$n^k - \frac{(k-3)(k-2)}{2}{n^{k-4}}$

Comment: Make that $n^{k-2}$ in the second term

Comment: The formula needs revision.  For k = 5, the (k-3)(k-2)/2 doesn't work, so it might not work for other k as well.  Gotta feed cats first.

Comment: I'm overcounting again!

Comment: I just can say for alphabet of size $n$ longest possible string without repeats, is $$2\cdot{n \choose 2} + 3\cdot n$$
$3\cdot n$ is because you can have a strings of length $3$ with same elements, and $2 \cdot {n \choose 2}$ is because you just have just $2 \cdot {n \choose 2}$ different combination of this elements, and adding new combination causes to repeating. (I considered that you say about disjoint repeating).

Comment: @DanDonnelly Please fix your formula and post it as answers (with its derivation) if you are confident it is correct. It can then be voted and edited by others.

Comment: @Suresh: There are only finitely many square-free words over binary alphabets, but there are infinite square-free words over larger ones.

Comment: @Raphael right but the OP is not asking about square-free words.

Comment: @Suresh: Right. Just saying you should not pick binary alphabets as point of discussion as they are boring: there are no (long) square-free words with two symbols, so there are also no repeat-free. More symbols allow for (arbitrarily) long square-free words, so we have better chances there (if at all).

Answer (score 1):

*<sup>This answers the question after the number of repeat-free words per size, implying that the desired quantity even exists.</sup>*

**Definition:** Call $w \in \Sigma$ *repeat-free* if and only if it does not contain a factor $xyx$ with $x \in \Sigma^{\geq 2}$ and $y \in \Sigma^*$.

**Claim:** For given finite alphabet $\Sigma$ with $|\Sigma| = k$, there are no repeat-free words of length greater than $2k^2 + 1$.

**Proof Idea:** By pigeon-hole principle. Take a word $w$ of length $2k^2 + 2$ (or a longer word and consider its prefix of this length), i.e. $w = a_0a_0' \dots a_{k^2}a_{k^2}'$. Assume $w$ is repeat-free; that means that $a_ia_i' \neq a_ja_j'$ for all $i \neq j$ (otherwise we had a repeat). Therefore, there are $k^2 + 1$ many pairs of symbols; this contradicts $|\Sigma^2| = k^2$. So $w$ is not repeat-free. $\square$

Note that this is a rough proof: factors $a_i'a_{i+1}$ might create a repeat even sooner.

---

*Notation:*

- $\Sigma^{\geq k} = \bigcup_{i=k}^\infty \Sigma^i = \Sigma^* \setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{k-1} \Sigma^i$
- "factor" = "subword" = "substring"

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You've only proved a very crude and pretty obvious upper bound, the question asked for an exact formula.

Comment: @Gilles: I misread the question at first but thought I could leave what I wrote up here for others (e.g. Kaveh, who claimed there were infinitely many such words).

Comment: My comment is more tight than your answer.